# best way to wait a particular pid

Tags: linux, bash, pid

What is the **best way to wait a particular pid** from another shell *(ie without a loop)*

Actually I use this solution *(doesn't work if root is the owner)*:

```
while kill -0 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
do
   echo "waiting $pid"        
   sleep 10
done
```

Alternative *(doesn't work with zombie processus*)

```
while ps -p `cat $PID_FILE` > /dev/null 2>&1
do
    echo "waiting $pid" 
    sleep 10; 
done
```

Comment: Every solution will need to use a loop( even if it looks like it doesn't), if what you have works then it's hardly going to be resource intensive so I'd just stick with that.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/what-does-kill-0-do ==> Arf, kill -0 does'nt work for root process

Comment: check for `/proc/$pid` then, if it's not there the process is dead. Still need a loop though.

Comment: May be we can use inotify with /proc/$pid

Comment: PIDs are recycled. Just checking /proc/$pid might check a different process that was assigned the same pid. Note that on some systems, PIDs aren't sequential.

Comment: we can't combine inotify and /proc : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/inotify-does-not-work-on-proc-660591/

Comment: @choroba Any solution will be susceptible to race conditions

Comment: @choroba You could always validate using the starttime in `proc/$pid/stat` if you were really worried that another process started in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sad, apparently no solution without loop and no "event" API for process.

My prefered solution is

```
while [ -e /proc/$pid ]
do
   echo "waiting $pid"        
   sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you'd use the `wait` shell builtin:

```
wait $pid
```

Comment: wait : it's only for child process of the current shell

Comment: Oh, you wanted to wait for a child process of another shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't `wait` a process if you are not its parent. If you really want a way to get informed in another shell, you can work it around like this:

```
mkfifo process_done_fifo
do_your_job &
pid=$!
wait $pid
echo $pid > process_done_fifo
```

And in another shell:

```
while true; do
    read pid < process_done_fifo
    if [ $pid = $pid_you_are_waiting_for ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Well, still with a loop, but not a polling one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But seems to complex.